# What is the most efficient method to handle reading multiple patterns through multiple parts of a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that reads a log file and searches for various patterns in various parts of the file. I am trying to think of the best way to optimize this flow, and I currently have it set such that when searching through the file, it will only search through the areas needed (last 15 minutes of logging, first 15 minutes of logging, last hour, last 30 minutes, etc.).

As you can imagine, as the file size increases, the searches do as well. 
Most greps are `fgreps` with `-m / -c` to optimize them and use `sed` to portion out the file along with special redirection and `tac` in some cases to read from bottom up rather than top to bottom of the file to maximize efficiency. The main thing that I have not implemented is utilizing `LC_ALL=C` before our greps, but regardless of that, I are still looking for best practices and best performance gains in this.

```
FILENAME="filename" #Can be large large file 10s of GB
search1 = $(<$FILENAME tac | sed "/thirty_mins_ago/q" | fgrep -c -m 1 "FATAL")
search2 = $(<$FILENAME tac | sed "/fifteen_mins_ago/q" | fgrep -c -m 1 "Exception")
search3 = $(<$FILENAME cat | sed "/start_of_day_fifteen/q" | fgrep -c -m "Maintenance complete")

if [ $search1 -ge 1 ];
echo "FATAL ERRORS DETECTED"
fi
etc
```

Would storing the entire file in a variable result in a quicker read time for grep or would splitting the file into multiple variables corresponding to block of time and then grepping those provide significant performance improvements?

Any suggestions on best ways to optimize and improve efficiency of this is much appreciated.

Comment: With such a large file, I wouldn't go through this file more than once. Parse the file once and collect your different pattern findings. Also, if speed is an issue, you should not spawn subprocesses while going through the file. You could stick with the regexp matching features in bash, but I personally would use a different language for this kind of task - Ruby, Perl, Python or something like this.

Comment: Would you say that a single egrep with each possible pattern across the entire file and then storing the output in a variable would be better than an fgrep on sections of the file and storing those outputs?

Comment: He's saying don't use grep at all - use awk, perl, etc. to read the file once and look for all the patterns you're interested in all in one script.

Comment: bash is quite slow for stuff like this. Agree with the others: spawning multiple child process for each line of the file will absolutely kill you. Use a single programming language (no matter which one, any will do) where you can do the file I/O and pattern matching.

Comment: When testing using awk over fgrep -e and egrep for different commands, I received much better returns sticking with grep (still not as fast as desired though)

time awk=$(fgrep -e 'ERROR' -e 'FATAL' -e 'DEAD' -e "Exception" log)

real    0m0.811s
user    0m0.711s
sys     0m0.201s
time awk=$(awk '/ERROR/ || /FATAL/ || /DEAD/ || /Exception/' log)

real    0m8.724s
user    0m8.494s
sys     0m0.316s